# How to show view for one item in a list and hide from others.?

Tags: java, android, list, android-recyclerview

I have a list with recycler view. I am showing another layout , on click of its parent layout of an item.

Now as I click items in list it shows the view for all the items, now I want to make the layout visible for only the clicked item and make it gone for other items.

Layout detail should only be visible on click of an item and only to the clicked item.

Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/lay_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="05dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="12dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/bg">

            <View
                android:layout_width="3dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/cardLineColor"></View>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_id"
                    android:layout_width="103dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ID"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                    android:text="23/3/2015"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_trans_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="sent money"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_trans_type"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_trans_type"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_balance"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:text="$3214"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                    android:text="@string/balance"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/trans_background">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@color/cardLineColor1"></View>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout86"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout86"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_vendor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/vendor"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightGrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                    android:text="@string/vendor"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout86"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_trans_id"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="ID"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightGrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                    android:text="@string/transId"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:background="@drawable/trans_background">

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@color/cardLineColor1"></View>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_credit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="$5858.0"
                    android:textColor="@color/lightGrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
                    android:text="@string/credit"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
public class TransactionHistoryListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Transaction> transactionList;
    private Context mContext;
    static final int TYPE_LOAD_TRANS = 0;



    public TransactionHistoryListAdapter(List<Transaction> transactionsList, Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.transactionList = transactionsList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        switch (viewType) {

            case TYPE_LOAD_TRANS:
                View v_header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction_item_layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new TransactionHistoryListHolder(v_header);
                break; 

        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_LOAD_TRANS) {
            TransactionHistoryListHolder transsHolder = (TransactionHistoryListHolder) holder;
            retriveAllTrans(transsHolder, position);
        } else {
        }

    }
    public void retriveAllTrans(final TransactionHistoryListHolder holder, final int position) {


        final Transaction data = transactionList.get(position);


        holder.txt_id.setText(data.getId());
        holder.txt_date.setText(data.getDate());
        holder.txt_trans_type.setText(data.getType());
        holder.txt_balance.setText(data.getBalance());


        holder.lay_row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        Transaction obj = transactionList.get(position);

        if (obj.typeToDisp == 0) {
            return TYPE_LOAD_TRANS;
        }
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return transactionList.size();
    }
}
```

How can we do it?

EDIT :

I tried to do this way :

```
   public class TransactionHistoryListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public TransactionHistoryListAdapter(List<Transaction> transactionsList, Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.transactionList = transactionsList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        switch (viewType) {

            case TYPE_LOAD_TRANS:
                View v_header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction_item_layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new TransactionHistoryListHolder(v_header);
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Transaction data = transactionList.get(position);
        if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_LOAD_TRANS) {


            TransactionHistoryListHolder transsHolder = (TransactionHistoryListHolder) holder;

            if (data.isVisible()){
                transsHolder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                transsHolder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            retriveAllTrans(transsHolder, position);
        } else {
        }

    }

    public void retriveAllTrans(final TransactionHistoryListHolder holder, final int position) {


        final Transaction data = transactionList.get(position);


        holder.txt_id.setText(data.getId());
        holder.txt_date.setText(data.getDate());
        holder.txt_trans_type.setText(data.getType());
        holder.txt_balance.setText(data.getBalance());


        holder.lay_row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



               if (data.isVisible()) { // initially it will be falsedata.setVisible(false);

                    data.setVisible(true);
                    holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                   data.setVisible(false);
                    holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   notifyDataSetChanged();

                }


            }
        });


        for (int i=0;i< transactionList.size();i++)
        {
            if(i==position) {
                data.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                data.setVisible(false);
            }
        }


    }

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        Transaction obj = transactionList.get(position);

        if (obj.typeToDisp == 0) {
            return TYPE_LOAD_TRANS;
        } 

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return transactionList.size();
    }
}
```

Its not working out.

Please help. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the flag in you model to hold the view state and show only if the condition satisfied with your model. For your reference in your Transaction model declare the field like this

```
public class Transaction {
 .....
 boolean isVisible;

 public void setIsVisible(boolean isVisible){
   this.isVisible = isVisible;
  }

 public boolean isVisible(){
    return isVisible;
 }
 }
```

then in you adapter class inside onClickListener set flag like this

```
   holder.lay_row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (data.isVisble()) { // initially it will be false
            data.setIsVisible(false);
            holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
            data.setIsVisible(true);
            holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.Visible);
            }

        }
    });
```

this will show your view but on scrolling views will be recycled and set to default state so to overcome this issue you must update your view state inside onBindView

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     final Transaction data = transactionList.get(position);
    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_LOAD_TRANS) {
        if (data.isVisible()){
        holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
         holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
        TransactionHistoryListHolder transsHolder = (TransactionHistoryListHolder) holder;
        retriveAllTrans(transsHolder, position);
    } else {
    }

 }
```

this will fix your issue

Comment: its not working still I can see the layout for every item, for other items it dose  not hide.

Comment: hello are you there? @sohan shetty

Comment: are you having multiple view type ?